# Numerical Range in Decision Tree Classifier

Tags: machine-learning

Does Decision Tree Classifier works with Numerical Range?

In this example set of dataset.

[image: Dataset]

I am planning to test the data regarding the age range of :

- 18-25
- 26-30
- 31-40
- 41 and above

Using the Performance Score of these Employees, can the decision tree be able to make the decision by using age ranges? The objective of the program is to identity what affects this employees age ranges by using the numerical data under : Education, and # Of years Exp.

So the output would be(Using Gini Index here)

- **Age** |          **Factor that affect based on age range.**
- 18-25    Education 25%
- 25-30    #Of Years Exp 9.50%

Is it possible to train the algorithm by basing the Age Range and Performance Score?

Comment: [Statisticians tend to discourage binning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable), so why do this to your age variable at all?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but one must use a proper representation of the numerical range: this is an ordinal variable, i.e. it has an order but it's not continuous. Common options are:

- A range can be represented as a simple integer: 1 for the first range, 2 for the second range, etc.
- Or it could be represented with a value representing the range, for instance the middle of the range.

Comment: So its means that a flow like this :

example

Age Range : 18 to 25
Using dataset

1. Age 20 - Performance Score is : 3 
2. Age 23 - Performance Score is  : 2
3. Age 25 - Performance Score is : 1

Those 3 data of age ang their performance score can be used to find the factors that affects the employees?

Do you mean that the root node will hold the age range value and performance score?

Comment: @ViksMaxx I think there's a bit of confusion: first, normally one would "bin" the age value for every instance, not aggregate multiple instances. Otherwise if you're looking for finding average performance score by age group, there's no need for a decision tree. Also normally you don't decide what is the root node of the tree, the training stage should determine the variable and condition at every node. And finally there's no way to know in advance if this will actually work to predict the performance, it depends on your data: these features might be good indicators for the target... or not.

Comment: So if I will set the code or the dataset like this:
.
Age Range : 18-25 = 1, 26-30 = 2, 31-40 = 3, 41-above = 4. So the values 1,2,3,and 4 represents the each of one Age Range. And by each data age range together with its individual Performance value I might able to use the Education, and # Of years Exp columns in the dataset to train the data so that I can come up about the factors of what affecting about this age group. Am I right? sorry for being to confusing here.

Comment: @ViksMaxx this looks ok to me. Just an additional note: in theory it's preferable if all the intervals of values have the same length, but this also depend on your particular task and dataset.